# Remote LAN Behind VPN Server Not Working

Tags: openvpn

[image]

I have a remote LAN exported by using a VPN server which acts also as router, as in the picture. The server has two interfaces, one to the public Internet and one for internal hosts.

This is my server.conf:

```
# OpenVPN Port, Protocol, and the Tun
port 1194
proto udp
dev tap

# OpenVPN Server Certificate - CA, server key and certificate
ca /etc/openvpn/server/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server/lab.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server/lab.key

key-direction 0
#DH and CRL key
dh /etc/openvpn/server/dh.pem    

# Redirect all Connection through OpenVPN Server
server 10.15.128.0 255.255.255.0    
push "route 10.14.128.0 255.255.255.0 10.15.128.1"
push "route-gateway 10.15.128.1"


# Using the DNS from https://dns.watch
push "dhcp-option DNS 84.200.69.80"
push "dhcp-option DNS 84.200.70.40"

#Enable multiple clients to connect with the same certificate key
duplicate-cn
client-to-client
#client-cert-not-required
#username-as-common-name
# TLS Security
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA256
auth SHA512
auth-nocache

# Other Configuration
keepalive 20 60
persist-key
persist-tun     
compress lz4
daemon
```

The client config is:

```
client
float
dev tap
proto udp

remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194 udp

ca ca.crt
cert client01.crt
key client01.key

cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
auth-nocache
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA256

resolv-retry infinite
compress lz4
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
pull
verb 3
```

The routing table on client is:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
10.14.128.0     10.15.128.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tap0
10.15.128.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap0 
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
```

From client, I can ping the server 10.14.128.29 but not the hosts behind the server. I tcpdumped on host2 and actually I see pings from client, both request and response. Do I have to add manually the route on 10.14.128.12 ?

Comment: Have you enabled IP(v4) forwarding on the VPN server? And is it doing NAT for the VPN clients? (Btw, why do you even use tap instead of tun?)

Comment: You mean NAT for tun0/tap0?

Comment: Well, more precisely source NATing (a.k.a. IP masquerading) `10.15.128.0/24` to `10.14.128.29`. Otherwise you'll need the route `10.15.128.0/24 via 10.14.128.29` set up on / pushed via DHCP to the remote LAN hosts.

Comment: (But of course, you can do IP masquerading unconditionally, or, use the outbound interface as the only condition.)